# OneSignal iOS - Can't prevent webview

Tags: ios, push-notification, wkwebview, onesignal

I integrated OneSignal to my iOS-App (WKWebview). But its automatically opening another webview window. I just want to load the given URL into my Webview, not another one. Universal Links/Deep Linking is also integrated.

I read that I can give "additional data" to every send notification, but I do not really know how I can catch that inside my AppDelegate (or somewhere else).

I added OneSignal this way: 
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup

Comment: Not clear what you're asking

Comment: I just want to prevent that OneSignal opens the URL inside a webview window. Instead I want to catch the URL and do whatever I want with it.

Comment: any progress on that?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to do this in the AppDelegate.m

The payload will look like [this](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-native-sdk#section--osnotificationpayload-)

```
// (Optional) - Create block that will fire when a notification is tapped on.
    id notificationOpenedBlock = ^(OSNotificationOpenedResult *result) {
        OSNotificationPayload* payload = result.notification.payload;

        NSString* messageTitle = @"OneSignal Example";
        NSString* fullMessage = [payload.body copy];

        if (payload.additionalData) {        
                    if (payload.additionalData[@"OpenURL"])
                        redVC.receivedUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:(NSString *)payload.additionalData[@"OpenURL"]];
```

Comment: How do you do this in Swift?